# How to implement special behavior for grid cells only for one column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cells

I have the next grid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CustomerID1" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:Customer}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                               AutomationProperties.AutomationId="FirstNameID" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CustomerID2" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:Customer}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="LastNameID" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <EventSetter Event="Unselected"
                         Handler="UnselectedHandler" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

I have a specific column with specific styles for all cells in this column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CustomerID1" />
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:Customer}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" 
                       AutomationProperties.AutomationId="FirstNameID" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Also I have the overall styles for all cells in the grid:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <EventSetter Event="Unselected"
                     Handler="ExpressionUnselectedHandler" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

But `UnselectedHandler` doesn't handle this event.

How can I use specific and default styles for all cells at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the DataGrid.CellStyle with the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle.

Move the style in the DataGrid.CellStyle to the DataGrid.Resources:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <EventSetter Event="Unselected" Handler="UnselectedHandler" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

But it still won't work because the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle is still overriding it so you need to add to the style: BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}". This tells it to use the already defined style (in Grid.Resources) but add the following to it.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

And of course, update the other template column's style too.

Comment: It is works, but I already use BasedOn `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"
                                           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static themes:ResourceKeys.DataGridCellStyle}}">
                                        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId"
                                                Value="ChannelDescriptionCell" />
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>`
can I use more then 1 StaticResource?

Comment: If all your DataGridCells are based off that style then add it as the basedon to the style in the DataGrid.Resoures. Otherwise, maybe see this: https://swdeveloper.wordpress.com/2009/01/03/wpf-xaml-multiple-style-inheritance-and-markup-extensions/